# Windows 7 - See files inside folder / subfolder / zip and print to text

Tags: windows-7

I found on your site instructions for using the windows command line to print a list of all files in folders/subfolders (dir/s/b>filelist.txt).  This gets me very close to my goal but is just shy of reaching the finish line.

1 Main Folder / 50 Sub folders / Each sub folder contains 2-46 zip files / each zip file has 1 text file

I need to get a print out of all the text files that are in my zip files along with the modified date.  Using the code I found I get the main folder/subfolder/zip file name - I just need that last piece; text file name/date in the zip.  Any chance anyone has a magic trick to make that happen?

Comment: [Reading ZIP file contents without extraction using PowerShell](http://techibee.com/powershell/reading-zip-file-contents-without-extraction-using-powershell/2152)

Comment: Additionally, you can put your DIR command in a FOR loop and use `7z` with an "el" (l) switch to list the contents of the ZIP files.  See https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/commands/list.htm for this detail and I know it's possible as I've done it before but don't have time to write you a script for this right now. The Powershell method may be the way to go. With a little testing, trial and error, you should be able to get this working either way.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/).
2. Open PowerShell. In Windows 10, you can open PowerShell as Admin via <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>A</kbd>.
3. Change into the directory: `cd "C:\Program Files\7-Zip"`
4. Call the 7z binary using the `l` (lowercase L) [argument](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/commands/list.htm): `./7z l C:\my_folder\myZipFile.zip > C:\my_folder\zip_contents.txt`
5. Open `C:\my_folder\zip_contents.txt` in a text editor such as Notepad++.